# How does Fury know about this in Spider-Man: Far From Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, Nick Fury invites Peter Parker to help Quentin Beck capture/kill the Elementals. After the

> seemingly failed attempt to stop Molten Man, Beck finally defeats and kills him.

At this time Fury says to Spider-Man (paraphrasing here, I do not remember the exact quote):

> *He* [Tony Stark] *made you an Avenger; you need to start acting like one.*

How does Fury know this? I agree that Fury knew Peter was an Avenger; but how did he know that Tony *made* him an Avenger? Since the only other person present at that time was Doctor Strange in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

Answer (score 14):

#### People talk

Tony had 5 years post *Avengers: Infinity War* to have mentioned that he made Peter an Avenger and considering how much it affected him I'm sure he did. It was even one of the first things he says upon returning to Earth. In fact he even says it before asking where Pepper is, remember Tony is a father figure to Peter and Peter is like the son Tony never had.

> **Tony Stark:** I lost the kid.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

It seems highly likely that he would have told the other Avengers and certainly would have told Pepper. Whilst he personally wouldn't have told Fury it seems like something someone else would have told him *or* he left a note along with the E.D.I.T.H. glasses when preparing them.

It's also worth noting that Fury may not have known that Peter was an "official" Avenger, only Tony's protegee. Fury could just be paraphrasing the situation to emotionally manipulate Peter to do what he wants. Also selecting Peter to have the E.D.I.T.H. glasses and essentially treating him as the new Iron Man is enough for Fury to connect the dots to believe Peter is an Avenger.

Lastly, in the post credits scene for *Spider-Man: Far From Home* it is revealed that,

> that wasn't actually Fury but Talos. Talos is presumably largely ignorant to the customs of who is or isn't an Avenger and just believes any Earth superhero is one. It could just be one of those things that Talos would assume Fury would say but that he wouldn't to subtly imply it isn't actually Fury. There are a few of those dotted around the film.

Comment: Keep in mind, Fury is the one who arranged for them to assemble in the first place. He is well connected as far as the Avengers are concerned and would be kept aware of their current line up.